# Trying to show multiple <mat-error> messages with matAutocomplete and matInput in Reactive forms (Material 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I want to display a couple of error messages using `mat-error`. I am using Angular Material 2 components with Reactive forms. I am also using `errorStateMatcher` to control as for when the error message appears. This works well for built-in validators like `required`. However, for matAutocomplete, I also want to when `No Matching Records are found` (basically when the user types something which is not there in the drop-down).

> The `html` part of the form looks like below

```
                   <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput
                               [matAutocomplete]="insurerAuto"
                               formControlName="insurer"
                               [errorStateMatcher]="requiredErrorState"
                               (keydown)="PanelOptions($event, insurerAuto)"
                               placeholder="Insurer" required>
                        <mat-autocomplete #insurerAuto="matAutocomplete"
                                          [displayWith]="displayFn">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let insurer of filteredInsuranceVendors|async"
                                        [value]="insurer">
                                {{ insurer.name }}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-autocomplete>
                        <mat-error>{{errorMsgs.requiredMsg}}</mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

As you can see, I have a `mat-error` to display the 'required field` message. But I want something like this instead:

```
<mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput
                               [matAutocomplete]="insurerAuto"
                               formControlName="insurer"
                               [errorStateMatcher]="requiredErrorState"
                               (keydown)="PanelOptions($event, insurerAuto)"
                               placeholder="Insurer" required>
                        <mat-autocomplete #insurerAuto="matAutocomplete"
                                          [displayWith]="displayFn">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let insurer of filteredInsuranceVendors|async"
                                        [value]="insurer">
                                {{ insurer.name }}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-autocomplete>
                        <mat-error *ngIf="policyForm.get('policyType').get('subType').hasError('required')">{{errorMsgs.requiredMsg}}</mat-error>
                        <mat-error *ngIf="(filteredInsuranceVendors|async)?.length === 0">No Matching records found!</mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

With two `mat-error` tags with `*ngIf` conditions controlling as when to show the appropriate error messages. The problem I am having is with `filteredInsuranceVendors` as it's an `Observable` and I am using `async`, I am not sure how can I use it to compare the length.

> The component code block:

```
    /** Error when invalid control is dirty, touched, or submitted. */
export class RequiredErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
    isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
        const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
        return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
    }
}

export const errorMessages: { [key: string]: string } = {
    requiredMsg: 'This field is required'
};

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    requiredErrorState = new RequiredErrorStateMatcher();
    errorMsgs = errorMessages;
    filteredInsuranceVendors:  Observable<Array<object>>;

    filterInsuranceVendor(): void {
        const insurerControl = this.policyForm.get('insurerInfo.insurer');
        this.filteredInsuranceVendors = this.commonFilter(insurerControl, this.insuranceVendors);

    }

        commonFilter(control: AbstractControl, lst: Array<object>): Observable<any> {
        return control.valueChanges
            .map(lstObj => this.displayFn(lstObj))
            .map(ObjName =>
                ObjName ? this.utilityService.filterForAutocomplete(ObjName, lst) : lst.slice())
    }

}
```

I want to have my errorStateMatcher function to include both condtions like below.

```
        /** Error when invalid control is dirty, touched, or submitted. */
export class RequiredErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
    isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
       if (this. filteredInsuranceVendors && !this. filteredInsuranceVendors.length) {
            return true;
        }
        const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
        return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
    }
}
```

One of the problem is, I am not sure how to deal with `filteredInsuranceVendors` as it's Observable. I tried converting it to `Array<object>`, still I was not able to use it with `errorStateMatcher`.

Any input would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've just use `Validators.compose`

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
field: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(...)])],
...
}
```